# A regex to identify a single character (;) but not if is has a matching character (") next to it

Tags: regex

I need an RegEx to identify the ; character but not if it is represented like this ";"

Example:

"apples";"Pears Bananas; Orange;Apple ";"";"Pear"

I want to match the ; as shown in bold below.

"apples";"Pears Bananas**;** Orange**;**Apple ";"";"Pear"

I have tried (;)(?:[^"]), however it matches  '; '  & ';A'. I just need a match on a single character ';' without the space or the A.
Looked everywhere, but can't work it out.
Thanks stackoverflow community!

Comment: Are you parsing CSV files? If so, quotes can be escaped by doubling, so `"foo "";"" bar"` would be a single field representing the string `foo ";" bar`. While this is probably unlikely to matter in real life, it's a potential bug.

Comment: Correct, however the data is the issue in this case as some data contained ; and it was bumping it across to the next column until Dawg came to my rescue.  Thanks Dawg!

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant. CSV is more complicated than just looking for semicolons and quotes; you need a parser to digest it reliably. Can you be sure that your input will never contain a newline, for example? Doesn’t the language you’re using provide an actual CSV parser?

Comment: I completely agree, in this instance the ; character was an invalid character for that data type and for some reason it was in the source data.  It's a bit difficult to clean up the source data (many different stakeholders), so this RegEx did the trick perfectly and also ensures that if the unwanted character sneaks in new data (somehow), then this will ensure it's managed before further processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookarounds:

```
(?<!");(?!")
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k8sj90/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  This is exactly what I was trying to achieve!  I will also look into lookarounds more for my learning! cheers!

Comment: If it works for you, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: [Great tutorial on lookarounds](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Will do.  just need to wait 9 mins before it will allow me :)